# How do I share a code analysis ruleset across .NET Core apps?

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-analysis

I'm trying to share a ruleset across multiple projects, and no matter what I try, each project uses its own ruleset within Dependencies > Analyzers.

I placed a ruleset in a common location for the solution. I then edited each project file to point to it:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\..\..\Solution Items\Shared.Minimum.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

My projects don't seem to use that ruleset. If I install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers from the project's properties, then those rules get used (they are located within Dependencies > Analyzers). If I uninstall Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, then nothing gets used.

How can I get it so each project uses the shared ruleset? Do I install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers for the project? Do I have to disable all the rules within Dependencies > Analyzers? I'm missing something.

Comment: You certainly don't need to install `FxCopAnalyzers` unless you explicitly want to use them. Have you tried to select the ruleset from the UI (Project > Properties)? VS normally copies the ruleset to the project's folder

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't think rulesets are selected that way anymore. When I go to the project's properties, then the Code Analysis tab, there is nowhere to specify the ruleset.

Comment: Huh, there was an earlier version of VS2019 that allowed this (I did this plenty of times this year), but doesn't seem to be the case anymore... What happens if you try to put the ruleset in the project's folder though?

Comment: I don't want the ruleset in the project's folder because I want to share it. I'm surprised that this is this difficult. Sharing a ruleset should be a common thing. Anyway, I may just give up and use the built-in rules. The only thing that sucks about that is having to set up each of our 30 projects the same way.

Comment: I asked you to test that because it might be that it's just the path not being resolved correctly

Comment: Good thought. I tried it and still have the same issue. I also tried adding the file (in the solution folder) as a link and the path exactly matched what I already had, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> If I install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers from the project's properties, then those rules get used (they are located within Dependencies > Analyzers). If I uninstall Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, then nothing gets used.

That's the problem with the FxCopAnalyzers; they inject their own rulesets, which can supersede or interfere with your own. They can be manually disabled, however.

Try something like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(SolutionDir)..\..\Code Analysis\<ruleset-name-here>.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This will disable the built in rulesets. It's standard practice at my current employer.

Comment: I just tried this and changed some source code to violate CA2200 (rethrow to preserve stack). It correctly produced an error. However, to make sure it wasn't from the built-in rules, I changed the severity (in the built-in rule) to none. I compiled and the error went away. That tells me the built-in rules are still being consulted. Note that the built-in rules now have a yellow warning next to them, like they're disabled. But they look like they're still being considered.

Comment: OMG, I just figured something out. When I changed to severity for a built-in rule, within Dependencies > Analyzers, THE SHARED RULESET CHANGED AS WELL. They aren't separate rulesets. Since I have my project file pointing to the shared ruleset, the rules in Dependencies > Analyzers *ARE* the shared rules.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense; I was chewing on your comment over lunch and came up blank, glad you worked that out. Is the analyzer working correctly now?

Comment: Almost. I'm still seeing warnings when I build, even though I set every rule to "none" except for three rules, as a test. When I check the rule that's showing a warning, it's set to "none" in the shared ruleset, but "default" in Dependencies > Analyzers. I don't know why. This is getting frustrating. lol